# Error when linking a dynamic lib.so using Lua

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, lua, shared-libraries

### Problem Background:

- OS: Linux Ubuntu
- Compiler: gcc
- Launguage: C++
- 2 project:

  - Project 1: to build a dynamic lib using Lua;  (libBattleCore.so)
  - Project 2: to build a console application, using the libBattleCore.so generated by Project 1

### Problem description

Project 2 compile command:

```
g++ -Wall -fexceptions -O2 -o bin/Release/BattleConsole  libBattleCore.h main.cpp -I/home/Downloads/lua-5.2.3/install/include/ -L. -lBattleCore
```

Error Messages

```
./libBattleCore.so: undefined reference to `luaopen_table'
./libBattleCore.so: undefined reference to `lua_getfield'
./libBattleCore.so: undefined reference to `lua_isstring'
...
./libBattleCore.so: undefined reference to `lua_tolstring'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What's the problem and what's the solution? Thanks

#### additional information

Project 1 build command:

```
g++ -O2 -fPIC -shared -o bin/Release/libBattleCore.so -I/home/Downloads/lua-5.2.3/install/include/ -L/home/Downloads/lua-5.2.3/install/lib/ -llua Basic_Battle/Arsenal.cpp Basic_Battle/BaseEntity.cpp  ...(lots of cpp files)
```

ldd libBattleCore.so :

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffff7ffe000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f008f35a000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f008f054000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f008ee3d000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f008ea77000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f00946a8000)
```

Comment: What does `ldd libBattleCore.so` output?

Comment: I've edited the question. Seems that libBattleCore.so doesn't include anything from lua, then how to embed lua into it?

Comment: It's missing lua's so, add `-llua` and see if it's ok

Comment: There is already -llua in project 1 building command...  When add -llua in Project 2 building command, the same error messages appear

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved...

still compile the project 2 with lua...

compile command:

```
g++ -Wall -fexceptions -O2 -o bin/Release/BattleConsole  libBattleCore.h main.cpp -L. -lBattleCore -llua -ldl
```

dynamic lib (.so) should be copy to /usr/lib/
Then ldd BattleCosnole will list libBattleCore.so => /usr/ ... not "not found" again

I still want some other method to self define the route of .so

Thanks

Comment: You don't need liblua in `/usr/lib` you just need it in a path you've told the compiler/linker about with `-L`. That being said, yes, you need to link lua to the thing that uses it (generally the binary) though linking it from a self-contained library is also fine.